# Android - (Sqlite) How to know my current table primary key

Tags: android, sqlite

i am trying to retrieve my current table id (primary key), but my primary key is autoincremental, how can i know what is the value of id now? Is there any code to retrieve the id? If there is any, can you please provide me some example? Because i am really new to android. >< Thanks.

Comment: do you want to retrieve the current id value from your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert a row in SQLite Database, it returns the row ID. Have a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

Hope this helps.. :)

Example:

```
long rowId = database.insert(MYTABLE, null, mContentValues);
```

Now you have the rowId.. :)

Comment: Thanks. then how i get the returned ID? can u provide me an example?

Answer (score 0):

`select id from table desc limit 1` 
this query will return the recently inserted row id.